# Trying to connect to Sentry ver 1.7.30 with Spring Boot ver 1.5.7

Tags: spring-boot, sentry

Hi I am getting confused with setting up old version of Sentry(ver 1.7.30) with current Spring Boot project(ver 1.5.7).

Here's my part of Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
  
    ...

    implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-spring:1.7.30'
    implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-logback:1.7.30'
}
```

application-local.yml

```
sentry:
  dsn: https://dsnPath
```

logback-spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- sentry -->
<configuration>
  <appender name="Sentry" class="io.sentry.logback.SentryAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
      <level>WARN</level>
    </filter>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="Sentry" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

When I run the project on local laptop, I can see some exception logs on console but they don't show up on Sentry. One thing I'm sure is..there's log4j2-spring.xml before I created logback-spring.xml file only for Sentry and this might be a problem?

(I followed the instruction on official page - https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/legacy/spring/ - and it didn't work. Maybe I made mistake regarding resolver.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Curious but why wouldn't you update the Sentry SDK to the latest version which is tested with that Spring Boot version